# How to use populate method of mongoose for mongodb in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to read data from the mongo database , but I am getting error.
I will explain what I did.

1. create two schema

   ```
   let CompanySchema = new Schema({
       name: {type: String, required: true, max: 100},
       contactPerson: {type: String},
   });


   // Export the model
   module.exports = mongoose.model('Company', CompanySchema);
   let UserSchema = new Schema({
       name: {type: String, required: true, max: 100},
       companyId:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'companyId' }
   });
   // Export the model
   module.exports = mongoose.model('UserTest', UserSchema);
   ```
2. First, add one company like this.which is successfully added

   ```
   app.get('/addCompany', async (req, res) => {
   let company = new Company({
       name: 'Test 1',
       contactPerson: 'rajesh'
   })
   company.save(function (err) {
       if (err) {
           console.log(err);
           res.status(500).send(err);
           // return next(err);
       }
       res.send('company added successfully')
       //res.render('index', { title: 'Express'}) 
       });
    })
   ```

[image]

1. Then I added a user like this .which is successfully added.

   ```
   app.get('/addUser', async (req, res) => {
   let user = new User({
       name: 'Test 1',
       companyId: '5d3d46b2825d7f0eaf9d9d27'
   })
   user.save(function (err) {
       if (err) {
           console.log(err);
           res.status(500).send(err);
           // return next(err);
       }
       res.send('user added successfully')
       //res.render('index', { title: 'Express'}) 
      });
   })
   ```

[image]

**Now I am trying to fetch all user with `company detail`** and getting error

```
app.get('/getUser', async (req, res) => {

    User
        .find({})
        .populate('companyId') // only works if we pushed refs to person.eventsAttended
        .exec(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
             console.log(err)
                return;
            }
            res.send(data);
        });


})
```

**error**

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "companyId".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at new MissingSchemaError (/Users/b0207296/WebstormProjects/untitled2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/missingSchema.js:22:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.mode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try now after changing your second schema to this :

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, max: 100},
    companyId:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company' }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('UserTest', UserSchema);
```

Assuming `companyId's` has matching documents in  _id's of Company. Similar kind of functionality can also be achieved thru `$lookup` of mongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

in ref you should pass the Company instead of company id

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, max: 100},
    companyId:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company' }
});
```